# Pulled someone down from the stage

Tags: prepositions

I was wondering it, let's fancy this situation: *A singer is performing a song on a stage, and the stage is 3 meters higher than the audience (where people are on, seeing him perform the song), the singer is pulled down by a fan who was watching him*. So, how could I differ: **being pulled from the stage where he was performing the song** and **being pulled from the audience by a fan**? If I said: *He was pulled from the audience* - Someone could possible understand that he was performing on the audience and someone pulled him down from there. But I actually implied to say that *He was pulled down from the audience* (Someone who was in the audience pulled him down). So, given the information, how could I differ both?

> The singer was pulled from the audience - He was pulled by someone who
>   was in the audience, but he wasn't in the audience, he was on the
>   stage.
>
> The singer was pulled from the audience - He was on the audience,
>   performing from there, and someone pulled him down from that place,
>   i.e.: someone who wasn't on the audience, pulled him down from there
>   (there = the audience)

Comment: In the situation you're describing, the singer was pulled BY (someone) from the audience not FROM the audience.  "The singer was pulled from the audience" cannot mean the singer was on stage before that.

Comment: 'the singer was pulled -into- the audience', or 'the singer was pulled -up from- the audience' would solve your problem. 'into' and 'up'  simple as that

Comment: @Tom22 - What difference does adding an "up" to the statement make?

Comment: Generally, a stage is elevated('a raised floor or platform, typically in a theater, on which actors, entertainers, or speakers perform.'). You could also use 'onto' the stage, which would apply whether or not the stage was above or below the audience.

Comment: All of them ('into', 'up to', 'onto') suggest that the subject is being moved. You could use 'to' alone (instead of 'from') but then you would have a different sort of ambiguity.  "pulled to" also frequently means "attracted to" or "drawn towards" in a motivational sense.

Comment: @Tom22 - But if I used: *The singer was pulled up from the audience* - It would mean that the stage is in a higher level of height, of course, but it would also mean that the singer was below it, in the audience, and he was pulled onto the stage. Could I use these terms to be more specific: *He was pulled down from the stage into the audience* and *He was pulled up from the audience onto the stage* ?

Comment: I suggested using "to" to remove the ambiguities of using "from"

Comment: Your examples in your newest comment could work but were moving into proofreading now ... and style issues.  they are wordy and still awkward

Comment: @Tom22 - You meant they are unecessary?  Like I could simply replace them for something like  *He was pulled into the audience* and *He was pulled onto the stage* Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52495/discussion-between-tom22-and-haseo).

Comment: Yes, those short sentences were what I was suggesting

Answer (score 2):

The way you are phrasing this implies that the singer was previously on top of or in the audience, and someone pulled him down from there. Specifically the word 'from' is the problem here, as it indicates the original position of the singer. You could say 'The singer was pulled down *from* the stage *by* someone from the audience,' or you could say 'The singer was pulled *by* the audience *from* the stage.' You could even say 'A hand *from* the audience pulled the singer down *from* the stage.' However you would like to phrase it, you cannot say he was pulled *from* the audience and have the meaning you would like.

Comment: Yes, Cameron, I was aware of all these secondary ways to phrase it, but I thought there were other ways to say it.